# Dispose pattern for class with static methods using SystemEvents in WinForms control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, idisposable, systemevent

I have a WinForms control in which some UI elements are drawn with static methods of an internal class - something like this:

```cs
internal class DrawUIElement
{
  public static void DrawArrow(Graphics g, Rectangle rect)
  {
    // Drawing something on the Graphics g
  }
}
```

Now I need to modify this class to support high-res screens. The improved version of the class will draw UI elements depending on the screen resolution. This implies I need to do some calculations based on the screen's current DPI and re-calculate them when the DPI changes. My intention is to use the [SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged) event for that. I am going to add an event handler in the constructor of the DrawUIElement class and do all required recalculations when the DPI changes in the event handler:

```cs
static DrawUIElement()
{
    Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged;
}

private static void SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Recalculate internal parameters based on the new screen DPI
}
```

This WinForms control already creates instances of some classes employing the similar [SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.userpreferencechanged) event. Those classes implement the `Dispose()` method from the `IDisposable` pattern to release references to the SystemEvents_UserPreferenceChanged event handler to avoid resource leaking when the form with the control is closed.

The question is: do I also need to add the `Dispose()` method to my DrawUIElements class that will detach my SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged event handler from SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged to avoid resource leaking or there is no need to worry about this in a class containing only static methods?

Comment: Dispose() is meant to release a resource early, before the GC gets around to it.  You need to listen to that event for the life of the app.  That's a feature, not a resource leak.  There is no point in disposing anything a millisecond before the app terminates.

Comment: You will probably get a memory leak if forgot to unsubscribe from static event, during app runtime. But there is no point for disposal actually

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, as I understand, actually we will have just 1 instance of the DrawUIElement class in memory during the lifetime of the app. If I will recalculate some static integer/float fields of the class in the SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged event handler, nothing bad happens - right?

Comment: @HansPassant, can this architecture with the SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged event handler always living prevent the visual control from destroying/releasing properly when the form containing it is closed?

Comment: @TecMan yes, that's fine. You can get some leaks if forgot to unsubscribe from event, when it's not needed. But it seems that `DisplaySettingsChanged` is needed during all the time of your app lifetime

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, the event is needed while we have an instance of the control on a form. But in the general case an app can have more than one form, and not all forms may contain the control. That's the possible problem.